# Why does my python socket in a thread not always close properly (i.e. if i run the program many times in a row)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have the following code (with may debugging messages). If I run this a few times in a row (within seconds of each-other), i often get a address in use error. It doesn't happen every time.

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

When i don't get the error here is the output:

```
 trying to recv ('127.0.0.1', 38041)
 recved
 from client -->  None genuine without this seal!
 shutting down con
 closing con
 done closing con
 shutting down
 running server shutdown
 running server close
 done closing
 done shutting down
```

The following is my code:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


def shutdown_thread(t):
    print "shutting down"
    t.shutdown()
    while t.isAlive():
        sleep(.1)
    print "done shutting down"


def send_with_netcat(msg):
    nc = Popen(
        ['nc', '127.0.0.1', '8000'],
        stdin=PIPE,
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=STDOUT)

    result = nc.communicate(msg)
    return result


class Server(Thread):
    is_shutdown = False

    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()
        self.start_server()

    def start_server(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET,
            socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # "A socket is a 5 tuple (proto, local addr, local port,
        # remote addr, remote port).  SO_REUSEADDR just says that you
        # can reuse local addresses.  The 5 tuple still must be
        # unique!"
        self.server.setsockopt(
            socket.SOL_SOCKET,
            socket.SO_REUSEADDR,
            1)

        self.server = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET,
            socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # bind the socket
        # ERROR HAPPENS HERE, HOW TO DEAL DEAL WITH OR AVOID?
        self.server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8000))
        self.server.listen(5)

    def shutdown(self):
        self.is_shutdown = True

    def run(self):
        while not self.is_shutdown:
            con, addr = self.server.accept()
            print "trying to recv", addr
            buf = con.recv(128)
            print "recved"
            if len(buf) > 0:
                print "from client --> ", buf

            print "shutting down con"
            con.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            print "closing con"
            con.close()
            print "done closing con"
            sleep(.1)

        print "running server shutdown"
        self.server.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        print "running server close"
        self.server.close()
        print "done closing"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server()
    s.start()
    send_with_netcat("None genuine without this seal!")
    shutdown_thread(s)
    sleep(5)
```

If you find github more readable you can see the same code [here](https://github.com/SEOVictory/mitm-http-proxy/blob/3dfbe0856c37b1f69a54d53f531dae718a3c391e/tests/talk-talk-test.py)

Oddly when i was trying to make this post it took may more times then needed. Could this be because many more connections are happening on my machine to randomize the client `nc` connection?

Thank you for any clarity on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `start_server()` method you're opening a socket in `self.server`, then you're setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` on this socket, and then you're calling `socket.socket()` again, which is erasing your `setsockopt()` call. Try deleting the second `socket.socket()` call. This should put the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag into effect.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was such a long bit of code i didn't think people would read it! And your answer makes perfect sense. I wonder why it ever worked?

Comment: Your code was fine. You set up a socket, then run `bind()` and `listen()` on this socket. Occasionally you could get into `Address already in use` error when re-running your server, but only in cases when the socket on the server side was still in TIME_WAIT state. Otherwise, your system was perfectly fine to re-run your server. Setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag tells your kernel to re-use the port while `bind()`-ing even if the port is blocked by TIME_WAIT state. Check this out for more info: http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-4.html